# Spam protection in Phpfox

Tags: php, plugins, spam-prevention, phpfox, akismet

I have a website customized using phpfox which has no spam protection yet. Now there are lots of spam for feeds and blogs in the database. So the database grows large.

I searched for spam protection plugins for phpfox and found Akismet to be useful which is a paid service. Also Akismet can protect only the spam which comes after installing it.

But i have to remove the spam that are loaded in the database and also protect the spam in future.

Is there any plugin to remove spam from database for phpfox?

Thanks...

Comment: could you describe more what type of span are they ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best option is to just ignore it, let them sign up and make your Registered user group have zero privileges, so they can't post anything or spam anyone, then have a certain criteria, for example they need to upload a photo, and make that a Promotion so they get promoted to a user group with normal privileges. You will accumulate fake email accounts but that is tiny and you can easily clean users who haven't logged in after a month for example.

Answer (score 0):

Akismet is focused to protect wordpress sites and is now available for free (not sure as a trial or full). Actually there is no third party available that guarantees 100% protection against spam. You can try reCaptcha. I think it is the best free tool a phpfox user can use to prevent spambots. Also there are some Menus available in the admincp area that works pretty good to stop spams from entering your site.
One suggestion: you should not ignore spam.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. A simple antispam question at registration and login time, solve my problem. For some reason, there are bots that look in PHPFOX servers, its my best guess. A day after I installed live server, a lot of dummy accounts invaded and posted weird non sense comments, and had to erase them manually. A pain in the butt.

You need to go to to the admin panel **/admincp and then select Modules, then User**. Use the question option were you can create your own answers **(Anti Spam Questions)**. Once a month you change the question so your community members are able to answer. I created a local question such capital city of different states in my country. My site is in spanish, bots cant login and there is no spam ever since.

That fixed my problem. No more spam. Good luck !